# Fail to upload file to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

When trying to save a file on S3 i got the exception:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1216) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1162) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:811) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:779) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:753) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:713) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:695) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:559) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:539) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5437) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketRegionViaHeadRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:6408) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.fetchRegionFromCache(AmazonS3Client.java:6381) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5422) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5384) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:421) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:6508) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1856) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1816) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at 
    ... 138 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:451) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:175) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
```

My java code to create the S3 client:

```
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
config.setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS * 1000);
config.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(null, RetryPolicy.BackoffStrategy.NO_DELAY, 3, false));

AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(config)
        .withCredentials(getAWSCredentialsProvider())
        .enableForceGlobalBucketAccess();
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);

client = builder.build();
```

Is this exception related to the configuration issue? or code issue?
anyone can help here to understand what is the problem

Comment: What is `endpoint`?

Comment: endpoint is empty, i change the code

Comment: put .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true) in builder and retry

Comment: withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true) did not help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that `endpoint` specifies the protocol or that it is a valid HTTPS endpoint. If you neglect to provide a `http://` prefix, the endpoint is considered to be HTTPS by default.